# pass data from remote loaded content to another php page using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i have a situation hear. i am loading mysql records from remote data.php page using ajax. its fetching all the records and showing on page perfectly on user.php.

now each record is having comment option like facebook. when i post comment it should send form data contain id, comment text and coment id to comment.php page. for that i am using ajax to send the data below is my ajax

```
$(function(){
$(document).on('submit','.comment_p',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
var com_dis= $("#comment_disc").val();
if(com_dis=='')
     {
    alert('Please add your comment');
     } else{
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/comment_update.php",
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
           }
       });
     }
     return false;
    }); 
});
```

and example image

[image]

Now my problem is if i post a comment on last record its working fine and after its working fine with other records also.

but on page load if i directly post comment other then last record its not posting data to php page.

if at least one time i post comment on last record then its working fine with other records. i feel very strange.

below is my remote loaded records php page form.

```
<form method="post" id="'.$row['id'].'" class="comment_p">
                         <input id="post_id" type="hidden" name="post_id" value="'.$row['id'].'">
                        <textarea id="comment_disc" name="comment_disc" rows="2" cols="48"></textarea>
                        <button id="com_submit" type="submit" class="btn btnbg">Post comment</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="[ btn btn-default ]">Cancel</button>
                        </form>
```

i hope you understand.

Comment: Try it by changing on('submit' to on('click'....And use $(this) while fetching comment related data...Check browser console as well

Comment: below answer is worked thank you  for your replay Mangesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
var com_dis= $(this).find("#comment_disc").val();
```

Note:Ids should be unique on the page

Comment: you know it took 25 min to write this question to make it understand. you rock. this is the correct answer. thank you. could you explain why its failed before

Comment: after success i want to fade out this class .panel-zesteve-comment and fade in the resonance data

Comment: when you where doing ` $("#comment_disc").val();` you where selecting the first textarea from the page with that id, now you select the textarea from the curent form

Comment: for the fade you can use `fade()`

Comment: its a toggle when i click it open a text box on click cancel it close. i dont know what to do after ajax success call to close this text box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108811/discussion-between-asesha-george-and-madalin-ivascu).